# Regex in Google Sheets full value + Value Splited

Tags: regex, split

In SpreadSheet I have the following text:

```
Ann Nutr Metab. 2022 May 11:1-8. doi: 10.1
```

Need to extract the date (2022 May 11) and split it in columns (year/month/date)

In B1 y wrote the formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$1,"(((?:\d){4})(...\w)\s(\d*)).*?:")
```

But for some reason I have the date required in the formula cell plus the date splited (four colums) and I only need the columns for (year/month/date)

```
2022 May 11|2022|May|11|
```

How can I recode to have this? `|2022|May|11|`
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=split(regexextract(A1,".*(\d{4} \w+ \d+).*")," ")
```

[image]